# What are "sunset additives"?

Tags: terminology, nutrition, tooth-decay, poison, dyes

In relation to stories such as this one, with the (probably sensationalized?) headline of "Nigerians boycott Coca-Cola drinks after court rules them 'poisonous'":

> Consumers of Sprite and Fanta have more to worry about than rotting
>   teeth according to a Lagos High Court judge, who ruled that the
>   Coca-Cola products could be "poisonous."
>
> The court held that **high levels of benzoic acid and sunset additives**
>   in the popular soft drinks could pose a health risk to consumers when
>   mixed with ascorbic acid, commonly known as vitamin C, according to
>   local media.
>
> http://edition.cnn.com/2017/03/28/africa/nigeria-coca-cola-case/index.html

I understand benzoic acid and ascorbic acid, but in this context what are sunset additives?

The term seems to get thrown around in every article that discusses the subject, but none of them seem to offer a specific definition of what compound/compounds are covered.

Is "sunset additives" just what 'FD&C Yellow' is known as overseas?  Or is it an actual class of additives?  Or some other compound entirely?  And how toxic is it, relative to the other ingredients in the soda?